# openshift dando problema

Tags: cloud, node.js

bom galera eu tenho alguns projetos no openshift mas como eles nao dao suporte a ninguem pelo site da empresa entao eles usão o stackoverflow para responder as perguntas das pessoas:

pra quem nao sabe o openshift é uma empresa de cloud(nuvem) onde voce ospeda um aplicativo e ele fica funcionando numa maquina que nunca desliga e etc...

a primeira coisa é como acessar o aplicativo no openshift? tenho dois aplicativos escrito para node.js mas nao temos como ver se eles funcionarao ou nao o aplicativo é até eles que ensinao a instalar estou falando do aplicativo chatty onde ele é um webchat que usar node.js e socket.io para funcionar deveria estar funcionando pelo linkin que aparece quando ele esta funcionando que é esse aqui:
chatty-xatevo.rhcloud.com

ao acessar a pagina que o openshift nos mostra que deveria ser a pagina do apps nao se pode visualizar nada, senao um tutorial que ensina a instalar o apps.

e outra coisa pessoas me disserao que era pra mim configurar a porta de 8000 para 8080 ja fiz isso e nada unica coisa que vi é que o apps funciona nesse link

chatty-xatevo.rhcloud.com:8000 
mas nesse nao abre a pagina

chatty-xatevo.rhcloud.com:8080.

pra quem quiser testar é só acessar no github e fazer upload do apps para o openshift por essa pagina:

https://github.com/jeremyosborne/chatty

perguntas sao onde estao os aplicativos? oque deu errado se tudo correu bem como acessar remotamente o aplicativo?

ja li todos os tutoriais do openshift mas nao vi nada explicando isso, inclusive ja até acessei o openshift pelo filezilla.
se voce ja usou o openshift por favor nos de uma luz.